# Problem in files paths when trying to include them into index page

Tags: java, jsp, path

When I make include 
     <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/Header.jspf" %>

The images inside the header are not reachable also css files are not linked correctly !!, here's the hierarchy of my files

[image]

in StudentIndex.jsp I make like this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/StudentStyle.css"/>
<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/Header.jspf" %>
```

and in the Header.jspf

```
<link href="../css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<img src="../images/iuglogo.gif" alt="IUG logo" id="IUGlogoStyle"/>
```

**EDIT**

when I run StudentIndex.jsp, all the files are running correctly

```
http://localhost:8080/OnlineQuerySystemNew/Student/StudentIndex.jsp
```

but when the request is forwarded from the servlet to the StudentIndex page no images and no css files are attached

```
http://localhost:8080/OnlineQuerySystemNew/StudentManagementServlet?param=activationOptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put this code in your .jspf file:

```
<link href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/iuglogo.gif" alt="IUG logo" id="IUGlogoStyle"/>
```

You can also change `<%= request.getContextPath() %>` to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` if you are using <strike>jstl</strike> [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Comment: [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) must not be confused with [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). What you're showing (as the *right* approach) is just EL.

Answer (score 2):

- Get [JSTL](http://jstl.java.net/)
- Include taglib in your jsp pages like this -

> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

- Use [url tag](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn) get rid of your pain. Like this -

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value="/css/Style.css" />' />
> <img src='<c:url value="/images/iuglogo.gif" />' alt="IUG logo" id="IUGlogoStyle"/>
> ```